# Imprimir con PHP una fecha con números de día

Tags: php

Tengo un problema en el que no puedo ponerle el numero del día al nombre del día, muestro el código así se entiende mejor.

```
    public function get_all_available($id_tipo_turno, $id_lugar){
        $result = array();

         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('cronograma');
         $this->db->where('id_tipo_turno', $id_tipo_turno);
         $this->db->where('id_lugar', $id_lugar);

         $query=$this->db->get();
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
         {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $id_cronograma = $row->id_cronograma;
            }
        }

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('cronograma_dia_semana c');
        $this->db->where('id_cronograma', $id_cronograma);

        $query=$this->db->get();
        $dias = [];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $dias[] = (object)array(

                    'id_dia_semana' => $row->id_dia_semana, 
                    'hora_inicio'   => $row->hora_inicio,
                    'hora_fin'      => $row->hora_fin,
                    'intervalo'     => $row->intervalo,
                    'name_en'       => $this->get_day_name((int)$row->id_dia_semana),
                    'name_es'       => '',
                );
            }
        }

        $day_name = date('l'); // Tuesday
        $day_number = (int)date('j'); // 8

        
        $limit = 21;
        $index = 0;
        $fechas_de_atencion =[];
        
        for( $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){
            
            $finded = false;

            foreach($dias as $d){
                if( $d->name_en === $day_name ){
                    $finded = true; 
                    $day_number++;      

                }
                
            }

            if( $finded ){
        
                $fechas_de_atencion[] = $day_name .' '. $day_number; // mas el numero de dia ????
            }
            
            $day_name  = date('l', strtotime($day_name . '+1 day')); 
            

        }

        echo json_encode($fechas_de_atencion);

        return $result;
        
    }
```

Ese método me imprime lo siguiente:

> ["Friday 10","Monday 11","Friday 12","Monday 13","Friday 14","Monday 15"]{"success":true,"message":"","data":[]}

Esto hace lo siguiente, busca días disponibles para sacar un turno X, en mi base de datos tengo que LUNES Y VIERNES están disponibles, y le pongo un limite de 21 días para que me muestre turnos. debería mostrarme esto:

> VIERNES 12, LUNES 15, VIERNES 19, LUNES 22, VIERNES 26, LUNES 29

Los números de días es lo que no se calcular, muchas gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 1):

PHP tiene [funciones builtin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) para hacer operaciones aritméticas con fechas. No debes hacerlo manualmente con incrementales ya que tendrás complejidad innecesaria cuando la fecha llegue a 30, 31, 1ro, si es bisiesto o cambie el año. Ejemplo de uso:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime('NOW'); // Ejemplo con Hoy
$test_day = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-03-20'); // Dia cualquiera

$now->modify('+1 day'); // Mañana
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
// Imprime: 2021-03-10

// Se puede poner en variable el incremental, por ejemplo para un ciclo.
$add = 1;
$now->modify('+'.$add.' day');
echo $now; // Pasado mañana
// Imprime: 2021-03-11

$test_day->modify('+5 day'); // +5 días
echo $test_day->format('Y-m-d');
// Imprime: 2021-03-25

$test_day->modify('+1 month'); // +1 mes (sumado a los 5 días anteriores)
$days = array('Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo');
$var = explode(",", $test_day->format('N,d'));
echo $days[$var[0]-1] . ' ' . $var[1];
// Imprime: Domingo 25
```

Adicional, puedes ver los [formatos de salida](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias aeportugal, lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d'); // 2021-03-09
        $limit = 21;
        $fechas_de_atencion =[];


        for( $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){

            //$dia_actual = $this->dame_el_dia($fecha); // aca tiene tuesday martes
            $dia_actual = date('l', strtotime($fecha));
            $finded = false;
            foreach($dias as $d){
                if( $d->name_en === $dia_actual ){
                    $finded = true;         
                }
            }

            if( $finded ){
        
                $fechas_de_atencion[] = date('l', strtotime($fecha)) . ' '. date('d', strtotime($fecha));
            }
            
            $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha . '+1 day')); 
            
        }

        echo json_encode($fechas_de_atencion);

        return $result;
```

Comment: Si la respuesta de @aeportugal te fue útil para llegar a la solución, deberías marcarla como aceptada y agradecer en los comentarios en lugar de publicar otra respuesta.